# Visual Studio Code snippet prefix icon customization

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I made a VS Code snippet extension and the only thing to finish my extension is that little icon on the left in the snippet (snippet prefix icon), but I have no idea how to set it.

[image: screenshot showing example]

Comment: What do you want to change it to?

Comment: Docs are here: [IntelliSense § Types of completions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions)

Comment: I'd like to change it to a method

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can if you make your snippets via a snippet extension.  That icon is controlled by the `kind` property of a `CompletionItem`.  So this works if you make your own `CompletionItems`:

```js
item.kind = vscode.CompletionItemKind.Method;
```

But in a snippet extension there is no opportunity to set the `kind`, so vscode must be doing this behind the scenes:

```js
  item.kind = vscode.CompletionItemKind.Snippet;
```

If you really really wanted the `Method` icon you would have to use a `vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider()` and in that `insertText` the completion item as a `SnippetString` and set the `kind` to `Method` as shown above.  Probably not worth the effort...